# When I load my json file i get this error: Exception has occurred: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json

I can't find anything to support this issue, I have read that the json itself maybe malformed however im new to json and can't spot anything wrong with my format

My code for loading the json looks like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

def main():
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    pprint(data)

main()
```

the code that writes the json file looks like this:

```
import json    
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:

    #data pulled from stored proc goes here...

    data = {}

    data[result.NUM] = {
        'Process': result.Rev,
        'Process Status': result.StatusID
    }    

    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
```

here is some sample data from the json:

```
{
    "12345678901234567": {
        "Process Status": 0,
        "Process": "fittingspa"
    }
}{
    "12345678901234567": {
        "Process Status": 0,
        "Process": "aprocess"
    }
}{
    "12345678901234567": {
        "Process Status": 1,
        "Process": "Development"
    }
}
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb added a few lines to the question

Comment: This does not look like a valid json.

Comment: @Dimitar ok, what about it isnt valid?

Comment: There is no root element at first, second it looks like several object literals put together. You can inspect this piece with some online json validator and probably more errors will appear.

Comment: @snakecharmerb shall i enter some delimiters within the dump?

Comment: Your example string is not a valid JSON. That's what the exception tells you. You seem to have a list of JSONs that is not comma-separated. If you want a json it would look like this: {"key1": {...}, "key2": {...}}.

Comment: @BoboDarph so i found the real issue was the json.dump line was within a for statement (as part of my data scraping), this caused a new dictionary to be made every time the loop was run therefore producing a malformed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **JSON** file is malformed, **JSON** object **must have only one top level**, try this example.

```
{
  "12345678901234567": {
        "Process Status": 0,
        "Process": "fittingspa"
    },

  "12345678901234563": {
        "Process Status": 0,
        "Process": "aprocess"
    },

    "12345678901234561": {
      "Process Status": 1,
      "Process": "Development"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great thanks, I am new to json and moving slowly! To solve the issue i have just used your example for now. I think the real issue lies in the json.dump part

Comment: You got the `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` error, and it's usually means that something wrong with json object/file, I'm happy that it solved your problem.

Comment: so i found the real issue was the json.dump line was within a for statement (as part of my data scraping), this caused a new dictionary to be made every time the loop was run.